# Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 10 (Masking Layer)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, layer

Given the MWE below, Python=3.8.15, Tensorflow=2.11, I get the error as shown. Note that this does not occur when `layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0, name='mask1')` is commented out.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers

samples, timesteps, features = 32, 10, 8
inputs = np.random.random([samples, timesteps, features]).astype(np.float32)
inputs[:, 3, :] = 0.
inputs[:, 5, :] = 0.
print(inputs.shape)

labels = np.mean(inputs, axis=2)
print(labels.shape)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(timesteps, features), name='input1'),
    layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0, name='mask1'),
    layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, name='lstm1'), name='bilstm1'),
    layers.Dropout(0.2, name='dropout1'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='dense2')
])

output = model(inputs)
print(output.shape)

model.compile(
    loss        = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
    optimizer   = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics     = [
        tf.keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error,
    ],
    run_eagerly = False,
)

print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(
    x      = inputs,
    y      = labels,
    epochs = 30
)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 36
     25 model.compile(
     26     loss        = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
     27     optimizer   = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
   (...)
     31     run_eagerly = False,
     32 )
     34 print(model.summary())
---> 36 history = model.fit(
     37     x      = inputs,
     38     y      = labels,
     39     epochs = 30
     40 )
...
    File "/home/dve/anaconda3/envs/trt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/losses_utils.py", line 224, in squeeze_or_expand_dimensions
        sample_weight = tf.squeeze(sample_weight, [-1])

    ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 10 for '{{node mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](mean_squared_error/mul_1)' with input shapes: [32,10].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your labels have the wrong shape of `(32,10)` but TF requires `(32, 10, 1)`. It tries to squeeze the last dimension (which it expects to be 1) but gets 10.

You can fix it by keeping the dimension when calculating the labels as follows:

```py
labels = np.mean(inputs, axis=2, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot! I incorrectly assumed that the last dimension would be ignored...

Comment: However, I now get the warning below... Any idea?

2023-01-04 22:16:41.705300: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/type_inference.cc:339] Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking. Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_INT32
    }
  }
}
 is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT

Comment: I can the code run just fine without any warnings under TF 2.10.

Comment: Okay cool, I'll use 2.10 then, been running into quite a number of such things with 2.11...  Thanks for all the help!